# In a Django form clean function, how can one reliably test if an optional field was filled out?

Tags: django, django-forms

In Django, I have a form class with a clean function. In this clean function, I check to see if an optional select box was filled out.

```
def clean_session_1(self):
    # Check if session_1 is filled out. 
    if self.cleaned_data['session_1']:
        # more validation
    return self.cleaned_data['session_1']
```

If the select box was filled out, then more validation of the field ensues.

For some reason, this code is not testing whether the field was filled out and runs "more validation" every time.

I was wondering how can one reliably test if this field "session_1" was filled out? Thanks!

Comment: As the answers below imply, but don't explicitly state: any time you need to access two or more fields from the form, you must use the main `clean` method. `clean_FOO` only reliably has access to that one field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access `self._raw_value('key')` to get the raw entry in the form field (i.e. just text, not processed to a python object).

Update: As Ahsan says, do it in the `clean` method. You should probably call the superclass clean method also.

Comment: It's unnecessary to call the superclass clean method if the form subclasses `forms.Form`. It's not in the [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) in the docs.

Comment: @Alasdair: Sure, unless forms.Form ever changes, or if any common functionality is ever factored into a common superclass. Of course, the question doesn't mention the base class.

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice, the `forms.Form` clean method isn't going to change, as that would break the forms api. Accessing the undocumented internal `self._raw_value` is much more likely to cause problems in future.

Comment: @Alasdair: You are assuming that no-one will ever install a package that in any way alters `forms.Form`.

Comment: @Alasdair: It's possible to alter something without breaking it. Putting functionality in forms.Form.clean() wouldn't likely break anything, and if it didn't, it would simply be inoperative if not called.

Comment: @Alasdair: Do you mean you think it's impossible alter something without breaking it? Or what else do you want to agree to disagree about?

Comment: I disagree that you should 'probably call the superclass clean method'. The possibility of a package monkey patching `forms.Form` doesn't convince me. Let's leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in form's clean method

```
def clean(self):
    data = self.data # data contains all fields, optional or required both
    optional_field = data.get('optional_field', None)
    # more validation
    return optional_field
```

Comment: Why access `self.data` instead of `self.cleaned_data`? An optional field with `required=False` will be in both, unless the input was invalid.